# Iphone Simulator Onscreen Keyboard Issue

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, keyboard, resignfirstresponder

I am making a Login Screen for my `ViewBased Application`.I am having a problem, when i click on the `UITextField` the onscreen screen pops up as it should. But when i am done with typing the `Onscreen` Keyboard is not removing from the screen.

Can any one suggest me how can i solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the delegate of the UITextField to ViewController class. Override textfieldShouldReturn and call resignFirstResponder...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
  return NO;
}
```

EDIT:

After seeing the comment It seems you are a beginner...[This](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-use-uitextfield-in-iphone-programming/137/) blog post tells about UITextField and delegates..Also when you have time, please read [this](http://www.thepensiveprogrammer.com/2010/05/objective-c-protocols-and-delegates.html) post too (to learn about protocols and delegates..)

Comment: How to set the delegate of UITextField to View Controller Class?And what the textFieldShouldReturn function does?Can you explain lil?